# Creating a seaborn factor plot using two data sets?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two data sets:

1. https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv
2. https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/BRFSS_Prevalence_and_Trends_Data__Tobacco_Use_-_Four_Level_Smoking_Data_for_2011.csv

From these two data sets, I have created two factor plots

1. `sns.factorplot(x='state', y='deaths', data=death, aspect = 4)
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)`

Result:  [image: Data Set 1]

2. `smoking['total_smoker'] = smoking['smoke_everyday'] + smoking['smoke_some_days']
   sns.factorplot(x='state', y='total_smoker', data=smoking.sort_values("state"), aspect = 3)
   plt.xticks(rotation = 90)`

Result: [image: Data Image 2]

I am looking for a way to visually compare the two lines.  Is there a way to create one factor plot using data from both sets in order to better compare data per state? Is there maybe a better way to show this visualization than what I am thinking? Apologies if my question is unclear, my experience with these tools are still lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use two `lineplot` on the same axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(..., ax=ax) # first dataset
sns.lineplot(..., ax=ax) # second dataset
```

Comment: This seems to only draw one line of data.  The other line is there, but it is flat and straight.

Comment: The range of your data seem very different. Maybe you should look at `twinx`